# How do I reset class names on all JSX elements in a component on props received?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm trying to create a container component that will hold filter data and pass it down to a component that will render the filtered list. This container component is getting it's data from a parent component. The filter works fine and passes the filtered list properly. I toggle a class on the filter tags onclick to change the css. My problem is if my container component has 1 data set rendered, and switches to a different data set with similar filter names, the class I use for active filters won't reset since React isn't re-rendering filters that don't change. For example, dataset 1 has the filters: hasNumbers, hasLetters and dataset 2 has the filters: hasNumbers, hasSpecialChars. If I toggle hasNumbers in dataset 1 then switch to dataset 2, the hasNumbers will keep its active class since React didn't re-render that (I think). This is only a problem with the class, the state is updating properly.

This is my container component:

```js
class containerComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = ({
      activeFilters: []
    })
    
    this.toggleItem = this.toggleItem.bind(this)
  }
  
  toggleItem(event) {
    event.target.classList.toggle('active');

    const targetItem = event.target.innerHTML;
    let _activeFilters = [...this.state.activeFilters];

    _activeFilters.indexOf(targetItem) === -1 ?
      _activeFilters = [..._activeFilters, targetItem] : _activeFilters = _activeFilters.filter(activeItem => activeItem != targetItem);

    this.setState({
      activeFilters: _activeFilters
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <FilterTags items={this.getItems()} toggleItem={this.toggleItem} />
    )
  }
}

export default containerComponent
```

And this is my component that renders the list of filter tags

```js
const FilterTags = ({items, toggleItem}) => {

  return (
    <ul className="filterList">
      <li>Filter: </li>
      {items.map((item, i) =>
        <li
          key={i}
          className={`itemFilter-${item.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}`}
          onClick={toggleItem}>{item}</li>
      )}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default FilterTags
```

Sorry if this is a mish mash of es5 and es6, it's been a while and I am trying to learn React and not-jQuery at the same time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

React use `key` to keep track of different elements of a list. In you case, it doesn't recreate element because you always use same `key` which is just the index. If you can use different keys when each time FilterTags get rendered, React will recreate you `<li>` elements and remove previously created elements. As a workaround, you can concatenate current time with the index and use it as the `key`.

```
const FilterTags = ({items, toggleItem}) => {
  const time = Date.now();
  return (
    <ul className="filterList">
      <li>Filter: </li>
      {items.map((item, i) =>
        <li
          key={time + "-" + i}
          className={`itemFilter-${item.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}`}
          onClick={toggleItem}>{item}</li>
      )}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default FilterTags
```

However, I don't recommend the approach you are using here. In React, it's not a good idea to mutate the DOM explicitly as you do with `event.target.classList.toggle('active')`. Instead, you should let React to that for you in the render method. Then you are always safe and won't face this kind of issues down the line. But you will have to pass `activeFilters` as a prop to your FilterTags component.

```
class ContainerComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = ({
      activeFilters: []
    })

    this.toggleItem = this.toggleItem.bind(this)
  }

  toggleItem(event) {

    const targetItem = event.target.textContent;
    let _activeFilters = [...this.state.activeFilters];

    _activeFilters.indexOf(targetItem) === -1 ?
      _activeFilters = [..._activeFilters, targetItem] : _activeFilters = _activeFilters.filter(activeItem => activeItem != targetItem);

    this.setState({
      activeFilters: _activeFilters
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <FilterTags items={this.getItems()} toggleItem={this.toggleItem} activeFilters={this.state.activeFilters}/>
    )
  }
}

export default containerComponent
```

and Then use it to conditionally add `active` class in the render method of FilterTags.

```
const FilterTags = ({items, toggleItem, activeFilters}) => {

  return (
    <ul className="filterList">
      <li>Filter: </li>
      {items.map((item, i) =>
        <li
          key={i}
          className={`itemFilter-${item.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}` + (activeFilters.indexOf(item) !== -1 ' active' : '')}
          onClick={toggleItem}>{item}</li>
      )}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default FilterTags
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. For some reason it didn't occur to me that using classList was affecting the dom dom and not the space dom. Just had to add the '?' in the second render func